# a question about @WebListener with @Service

Tags: java, spring-boot

When i use the @WebListener and @Service in the same class, the methods in the class will run twice. Why is that?

Example code:

```
@WebListener
@Service
public class WebContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(WebContextListener.class);


    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        ServletContext servletContext = sce.getServletContext();
        logger.info("web listener 启动,为什么会执行两次呢，Spring做了什么处理吗");
        logger.info("web listener runing,why this method ran twice,What did Spring do?");

    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {

    }
}
```

Comment: You are right. Thank you for reminding me that I will update the question later. By the way, the framework is Springboot 2.1.3

Answer (score 0):

I think because you use @Service and @WebListener.

I guess this will produce two instances of this class.

Try to remove @Service.

Check this out:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-servletcomponentscan

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I want to know more specific reasons